# adding percentage column by value in a column

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, categorical-data, feature-selection

I'm trying encoding categorical column value to percentage frequency (binary encoding) as new feature.

```
Value   Count   Frequency (%) 
20190   14723   16.2%    
20100   11235   12.4%    
20120   9449    10.4%    
20130   7744    8.5%     
20210   5920    6.5%     
20140   5192    5.7%     
20270   4324    4.8%     
20220   3800    4.2%     
20180   3707    4.1%     
20110   3031    3.3%     
Other values (28)   21572   23.8%
```

id tried this:

```
df1['binary_group_of_materials']=df1['A_group_of_materials'].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100
```

there is a new column but all the values are NaN.

output should be:

```
Value   Frequency (%) 
20190   16.2%    
20100   12.4%    
20120   10.4%    
20130   8.5%     
20210   6.5%     
20140   5.7%     
20270   4.8%     
20220   4.2%     
20180   4.1%     
20110   3.3%
```

Comment: can u post ur expected output

Comment: @sammywemmy , how do i do that? just tell me how did you edit my tabel and i will do the same.tnx in advanced

Comment: there should be a ```{}``` button when editing. Highlight the relevant code and click on the button. alternatively, u can hit the space bar four times to get it in code form

Comment: Some problem with answer?

Comment: @jezrael Sorry the answer is great! just published the output. tnx again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for new column:

```
s = df1['A_group_of_materials'].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100
df1['binary_group_of_materials'] = df1['A_group_of_materials'].map(s)
```

If need percentages:

```
df1['binary_group_of_materials'] = df1['A_group_of_materials'].map(s).round(1).astype(str) + '%'
```